# How to create custom field in Sales > order > create new order Grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I am working on Magento, I want to create new custom field with filter in `Sales > Order > Create new order > Add product` grid.

Let me know please how can i do it.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override a class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid`.

Go to your config.xml and add this

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        ......................          
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_create_search_grid>Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid</sales_order_create_search_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
.............
</global>
```

Now create a file `Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php` and have this code:

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid extends 
    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid
{

/**
 * Prepare collection to be displayed in the grid
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->setStore($this->getStore())
        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array_keys(
            Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/sales/order/create/available_product_types')->asArray()
        ))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('gift_message_available')
        //our new field.
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}


protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumn('type',
          array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Type'),
            'width' => '60px',
            'index' => 'type_id',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
      ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

This will add a product type in grid.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override a class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid to local code pool from core code pool

And in that add column whatever you want